# Неодинаковый размер теней налогичных view в lollipop

Tags: android

Необходимо сделать кнопку которая по нажатию преподнимается. Однако на android 5 размер тени отображаемой у элемента зависит от положения элемента по вертикали. То есть чем ниже кнопка, тем выше тень. Такое же поведение наблюдается, например, на cardView в приложениях google (PlayMarket, PlayNews). Можно ли избавиться от такого эффекта, чтобы кнопки выглядели одинаково?

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
    style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_blue"
    android:text="BUTTON" />

<View
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center|top"
    android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_blue"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:stateListAnimator="@xml/state_list_animator" />

<Button
    style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_blue"
    android:text="BUTTON" />

<View
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_blue"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:stateListAnimator="@xml/state_list_animator" />
</FrameLayout>
```

state_list_animator:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:state_pressed="true">
    <set>
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="100"
            android:propertyName="translationZ"
            android:valueTo="6"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="0"
            android:propertyName="elevation"
            android:valueTo="2"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
    </set>
</item>
<!-- base state -->
<item android:state_enabled="true">
    <set>
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="100"
            android:propertyName="translationZ"
            android:startDelay="20"
            android:valueTo="1"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="0"
            android:propertyName="elevation"
            android:valueTo="2"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
    </set>
</item>
</selector>
```

Результат:

[image: Результат]

Подробнее:

[image: подробнее]

Пример Google приложения:

[image: google приложение с CardViews]